# how to create a trigger in oracle that fires anytime, except when I use a netbeans application to modiify my database

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans

I created a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE DATA
(  name  char(30),
   day   integer,
   month integer,
   year  integer);
```

It's a simple one. I also created a trigger that restricts any action on my database from everywhere. But I still want to make changes on my database but only with a secure java application.

What should I modify in my trigger code?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tri_block
     BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON data
    BEGIN
       IF  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'hh24')) < 12
           OR TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'hh24')) >= 12
            OR TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'dy') in ('sun','sat') THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000, 'changes can not be made');
    END IF;
   END;
```

This is my trigger code.

Comment: We don't see any trigger code. Also sounds like a pretty bad idea.

Comment: use permissions to restrict access not triggers

Comment: To expand on what @davegreen100 said, on the database side of things, I would have at least two accounts - one that holds all your schema objects etc eg. app_owner and one that is used by your application, eg. app_user. Give the app_user account the necessary privileges to the stored procedures etc. Then it's a case of ensuring that only your application uses the app_user schema on top of all the usual precautions around allowing access to the app_owner schema.

Comment: I forgot to put the trigger code. Now it's on. Can you give me an example on my code? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your trigger code, have it fire if the MODULE doesn't show as your application.

Good applications identify themselves. If yours does, you can use this to decide if the trigger should fire or not.

Beware that users can use SQL to change their module by using ALTER SESSION SET commands.

[DOCS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_appinf.htm#i996826)

Comment: I put my trigger code.  Can you give me an example please? Thanks!

Comment: you want a LOGON trigger CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_user
  AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
  BEGIN
    do_stuff;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR
        (-20000, 'Unexpected error: '|| DBMS_Utility.Format_Error_Stack);
 END;
/

'do_stuff' will be your code to check if it's a netbeans app. if it isn't, setup your session monitoring/logging/auditing code.